# How to find SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken and SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken of specific iTunes App?

Tags: ios, ios8, storekit

this is code, i am using

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewControlleralloc] init];
// Configure View Controller
[storeProductViewController setDelegate:self];
NSDictionary *parameters;
parameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:kPlaylistID, SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken:kAffiliateID, 
SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken:kCampaignID};
```

Answer (score 3):

The keys you reference are part of [StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKStoreProductViewController). The affiliate and campaign tokens you reference are [SKStoreProductParameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Product_Dictionary_Keys) that became available with iOS 8.

In order to get those two tokens, you need to join the [iTunes App Store Affiliate Program](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes_app_store_affiliate_program.html).

- `SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken`: This is auto generated for you by the program. It will appear top right of screen once you're logged in.
- `SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken`: This is optional and user defined. You can add this in the [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/) tool. There is a popup you can display by clicking Add Campaign Token, after you've selected a product to link to.

[image]

Both of these tokens should be represented as NSString.

Note that the current iTunes App Store Affiliate Program is different than the LinkShare program of a few years ago.